# Could we use JavaFX with Eclipse RAP?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I just wanted to know if we could use Java FX with RAP. Also, Could you suggest me few good links or tutorials to study RAP and RCP?

Answer (score 1):

No you can not unless you make use of SWT on JavaFX port in the desktop. RAP is bound to the SWT-API